# webRTC Multiple Camera streaming

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, streaming

I'm trying to stream multiple carmeras over the network using webRTC. This is what im trying to do:
[image: 1]

I found [this](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/) which is what I want to do but for some reason, it's not working for me.

Is it possible to clone [this](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/devices/input-output) project, run it local server then access it remotely?

Comment: HI Ahmed, Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, yes i end up using openvidu which allowed me to create a session for every camera https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/tree/master/openvidu-js-node